# does python's append work with ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

quick question: 
I know ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) in google datastore, is seen as a list in python. But what I want to know is, suppose u have this class:

```
class Customer(ndb.Model):
    name = StringProperty()
    items = StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

and you create an instance:

```
custmr = Customer()
custmr.name = "Sam"
custmr.items = ['python','java','ruby']
custmr.put()
```

and save it... then later retrieve it...

```
q = Customer.query.filter(name="Sam")
custmr = q.get()
```

can I do this...

```
custmr.items.append('perl')
custmr.put()
```

and update the list??

if not, then how do I do it pls?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: poor sam getting perl

Comment: @Goyo I created a whole new dummy project for this purpose after seeing your question. You can mutate it. so yeah, append works and so does extend and all the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated) say you can mutate the list in place:

> When updating a repeated property, you can either assign it a new list or mutate the existing list in place. When you assign a new list, the types of the list items are validated immediately. Invalid item types (for example, assigning `[1, 2]` to `art.tags` above) raise an exception. When you mutate the list, the change is not validated immediately. Instead, the value will be validated when you write the entity to the Datastore.